# RECEIVE_SMS broadcast receiver not working?

Tags: android

I have looked at all of the "common" mistakes, but I haven't made on (unfortuantely).

I cannot for the life of me figure out why (at the very least), I'm not getting a log message!

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.permission.PREFS"
        android:description="@string/permdisc"
        android:label="Prefs"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.permission.PREFS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.permission.CONFIG"
        android:description="@string/permdiscconfig"
        android:label="Config"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.permission.CONFIG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ProcessSMS"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Launcher" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityConfig"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.permission.CONFIG" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Prefs"
            android:permission="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.permission.PREFS" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.PREFS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.cetagory.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".CodeReceive"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />

                <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".ReceiveSMS"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ReceiveSMS.java:

```
package com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReceiveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("User Track", "SMS Received!");

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        edit = prefs.edit();

        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";

        if (myBundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (messages[i].getMessageBody().toString()
                        .equals(prefs.getString("cbp_pass", null))) {

                    Log.d("User Track", "Message Equals Password!");
                    Intent start = new Intent(context, ProcessSMS.class);
                    start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    start.putExtra("Sender",
                            messages[i].getOriginatingAddress());
                    context.startActivity(start);

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I don't even get an 'SMS Received!' log message, which tells me this isn't working at all.

A second question is, how can I make it that an SMS bypasses the SMS app and just goes to my app?

Comment: `com.liamwli.spyware` and you expect help? Seriously?

Comment: @WarrenFaith I should have mentioned that this is a little private hobby project ;) You *won't* see it anywhere on the internet :)

Comment: Yeah this would be a good thing to know! :D ... Wait, a good spyware shouldn't be visible anywhere... so I still hope you use it only to spy on yourself... or to keep it as a proof of concept.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Exactly what I was planning to do :) They say it is possible, so I have to prove it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` permission. Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

to your manifest.

Comment: The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks, receiving only general feedback and often outright rejections are received with no explanations. Any ideas on how to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me since API level 23. We need to request permission at run time. Hope this can help anyone with similar issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462909/4544780

Comment: Which part of that SO link did you find helpful?

Comment: Here we need to request permission dynamically, and configure in AndroidManifest.xml seems not enough. 

We can request the permission immediately here for the first time run
`requestPermissions(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);`

Inside that, check with `checkSelfPermission()` for `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` and then, ask for it dynamically and handle request result.

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);`